# FluentD - Parsing Heroku’s Logplex format

Tags: heroku, fluentd

We’re using FluentD to send data over to our ELK stack. Heroku sends over logs in a BULK format which includes multiple log entries, separated by a new line.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with splitting incoming http requests in FluentD by newline? I saw examples of this in past versions < 1.0. There are also two Heroku+FluentD plugins, both of which no longer seem to work and are not maintained.

1. Can I use a parser to split the incoming message into multiple messages and emit each to FluentD, if so, how?
2. If not, is there a simpler way to get these bulk messages sent from Heroku into FluentD, split by new line?

**The bulk log messages Heroku posts look something like this:**

`83 <40>1 2012-11-30T06:45:29+00:00 host app web.3 - State changed from starting to up 119 <40>1 2012-11-30T06:45:26+00:00 host app web.3 - Starting process with command bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 24405`

So in our logging solution, we’re getting multiple rows per entry. We’ve tried multi line parsing, but that doesn’t seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by using the following [gem](https://github.com/wshihadeh/fluent-plugin-record-splitter)

Install the gem and use one of the following configs

Use this one of your events are separated with a new line

```
<match *.*>
  @type record_splitter
  tag splitted.log
  input_key message
  split_stratgey lines
  append_new_line true
  remove_new_line true
</match>
```

or use this one to split the lines with regex

```
<match *.*>
  @type record_splitter
  tag splitted.log
  input_key message
  split_stratgey regex
  split_regex /\d+\s<\d+>.+/
</match>
```

to be able to process the log lines further, you can add another output match for the tag used (example below to send logs to elk)

```
<filter splitted.log>
...
</filter>

<match splitted.log>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
</match>

<match **.**>
  @type elasticsearch
  ...
</match>
```

Comment: Can you have multiple matches? Can you then send this match splitted.log to another match to be sent out to a third party service? I thought match only processed the first match entry then stopped.

Comment: This blog can help you to understand how to do it exactly https://levelup.gitconnected.com/centralize-your-docker-logging-with-fluentd-a2b7e0a379ce

Comment: You are also correct, in case the match did not change the tag of the events, but this gem will change it and it will result in a new tag that was not matched but the first one :)